# Display notification whenever app is running or not

Tags: php, android

In my program, notification must be activated whenever app is running or not. Should I put my notification method in onCreate()? my notification is just like alarm. Please check alittle.

```
public String getCurrentTime(){
    Calendar c= Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ");
    String strDate = sdf.format(c.getTime());
    return strDate;
}
```

This is get the system time.

```
public void jsonen()
{
    int status=2;
    JSONObject json=null;

    String teamID=null;
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    //postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email",edit_txt_EmailAddress.getText().toString()));//// define the parameter
    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userID","396797666"));

    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
       .detectDiskReads().detectDiskWrites().detectNetwork() // StrictMode is most commonly used to catch accidental disk or network access on the application's main thread
       .penaltyLog().build());

    ArrayList<NameValuePair> pp = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    String response = null;
    try {
          response=CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/football365/notification.php", postParameters);
         // json=new JSONObject(response);
        //  teamID=json.getString("teamID");
         // Log.i("Team ID",teamID+"");
        }
   catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    JSONObject jsonobj = null;
    String alerttime=null;
    String beforematch=null;
    JSONArray jArray = null;
    String starttime=null;
try{

    jsonobj = new JSONObject (response);
    jArray=jsonobj.getJSONArray("notifications");

    Log.i("Current Time",jArray+"");
    Log.i("Current Time",getCurrentTime());

    for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){

        jsonobj=jArray.getJSONObject(i);

        alerttime=jsonobj.getString("alert");
        starttime=jsonobj.getString("startTime");
        beforematch=jsonobj.getString("beforeMatchTime");

        if(alerttime==getCurrentTime()){

                Notification(starttime);
                Log.i("Wintal", "wint");
        }
    }
    //teamStatus=jsonobj.getString("teamStatus");

}
catch(JSONException e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
}



Log.i("RESULT", jsonobj+"");
Log.i("time", alerttime+"");
Log.i("before Match",beforematch+"");
}
```

This is Checking.

```
public void Notification(String s)
{

        String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);

        int icon = R.drawable.notification_icon;
        CharSequence tickerText = "Ready for Play time."; // ticker-text
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence contentTitle = "Play Time";
        CharSequence contentText = "Your match is at "+s;
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this,ScheldueNotification .class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);

        // and this
        final int HELLO_ID = 1;
        mNotificationManager.notify(HELLO_ID, notification);

        notification.flags=Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
}
```

This is Notification part.
Please help.

Comment: Use alarmmanager and set local notification with some time it will trigger irrespective of your app running or not. http://justcallmebrian.com/2010/04/27/using-alarmmanager-to-schedule-activities-on-android/

Answer (score 0):

Use AlarmManger to notify at specific intervals.

Check this :

[Alaram Manager Description](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) and [Alarm Manager Example](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/use-androids-alarmmanager-to-schedule-an-event/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's not like that, be the example, Let's I'm a player of a team. I have to train at 2:00 and the notification should be show at 1:00, so the system time arrive at 1:00, and notification should be activated. I guess u get it.

Comment: Alarm Manger exactly does that.Check the link I provided you.

Answer (score 0):

Use AlarmManager with BroadcastReceiver.
Using alarm manager trigger the receiver and inside your receiver class have your notification method.
BroadcastReceiver allows you to run processes in background whether is app is running or not.